# constraint issue on iOS 13, looks different than iOS 12

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, ios13

i have issue with **bottom** constraint of my view on iOS 13, here is my single line of code that i have issue with it:
`myLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true`

this code works different on iOS 13 and iOS 12: (below images related to iOS 13 and it's debug view)
[image: iOS-13]

[image: iOS-13 View Debug]

in debug view it's looks different from simulator view, i don't know why?!

now if you see in below image: (related to iOS 12)
[image]

this is what i'm done until now:
when i remove height constraint on headerView(GreenImage) it's work normally, but when i set height on it, issue back :(
i create headerBackground constraint in **layoutSubviews()**
and create label bottom constraint in closure property like code below:

```
private lazy var headerView : HeaderView = {
        let view = HeaderView(layout: .login)
        let welcomeLabel = UILabel()
        view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)
        welcomeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        welcomeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        welcomeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        welcomeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        return view
    }()
```

Comment: Where do you create that constraint for "myLabel"?

Comment: @Julian i update my question, for you're answer in bottom of my question.

Comment: Where do you add the headerView to your layout? Where is this being called?

Comment: @Julian i add headerView into UIStackView(addArrangedSubview) also in layoutSubviews method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that I think in iOS 12 or earlier views has a default value of `clipToBounds = true`
which in iOS 13 is false
after I change the value my problem is solved and the front imageView clip from behind view.